# React native i can't build release get APK

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, apk

please how I can build release **APK** from react-native.

I try method in site react native [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android), but every try i get **app.aab** and **not get app.apk**.

Comment: What did you try? What settings did you use?

Answer (score 2):

In your `android/` folder, run the command `./gradlew assembleRelease`.

This will generate a `.apk` file in your `android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/` folder.